# Add the ability to flag comments

Tags: feature-request, android-app, comment-flags

Please add the ability to add comments to the Android app. Currently I cannot flag comments as being obsolete, too chatty, etc, as I run into them.

This isn't a feature in the mobile site view either, but you have the capacity to add it on the app at least, I hope!

Comment: What app version are you using currently? As of 1.0.11, you can flag comments. Also, I remember this issue has been addressed before.