# 'Loading the question failed.' on a question I just posted

Tags: bug, asking-questions, android-app

I just now [posted a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/221701/152515) from the Android app (the first I've actually published using it).

After telling me it was successfully submitted (which it was), I was taken to a screen in which I was presumably going to get to view my question. But on that very screen, I got a message saying: 'Loading the question failed.'

(The retry button didn't do anything.)

[image]

I'm using app version 1.0.11 on a HTC One running Android 4.3.

Here's what I did *exactly*:

1. Added tags to the question: [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), [android-app](/questions/tagged/android-app), then [flags](/questions/tagged/flags), then [comment-flags](/questions/tagged/comment-flags). (then removed [flags](/questions/tagged/flags))
2. Filled out the title
3. Filled out the body
4. Hit submit, without a preview.